# jQuery datepicker not showing in my App

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, datepicker

I'm trying to change my simple form default date format to jQuery datepicker on an events site I'm building. I've followed Ryan Bates' video but no joy. Here's my code -

Application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui/datepicker
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

Events.coffee

```
jQuery ->

  $("#datepicker").datepicker(
        dateFormat: "DD-mm-yy"


    );
```

Form -

```
<%= f.input :image, as: :file, label: 'Image' %>
<%= f.input :title, label: 'Title' %>
<%= f.input :location, label: 'Location' %>
<%= f.text_field :date, label: 'Date' %>
<%= f.input :time, label: 'Time' %>
<%= f.input :description, label: 'Description' %>
<%= f.input :organised_by, label: 'Organised by' %>
<%= f.input :organiser_description, label: 'Organiser description' %>
<%= f.input :url, label: "Link to Organiser site" %>
```

My Events Controller has the following method -

```
    def new
        @event = current_user.events.build

    end
```

I'm not sure if #current_user.events.build is what needs to be shown in the jQuery function. I'm obviously not identifying the element properly. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: where you define datepicker id in your form?

Comment: Hi, can you also share the rendrered html? It might be a frontend problem

Comment: Answer below sorted it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign an `id` for the ***form field*** for the ***datepicker*** to appear.

```
<%= f.text_field :date, id: 'datepicker', label: 'Date' %>
```

Comment: Hi, any idea how I get showAnim working? I've posted another question on here but none of the answers seem to work.